# How can I get a live Firebase result limited on creation?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, observable

I am developing an Iionic 3 - Firebase based chat application using Firebase Realtime Database for storing messages, loading them into the app and showing them immediately.

When a chat conversation opens, I load the messages using next limited query so after entering, I only who last 100 messages:

```
this.messagesRef = this.afDB.list(
    `/messages/${this.me.uid}/conversations/${this.contact.uid}/messages`, ref =>  
   .limitToLast(100)).valueChanges();
```

Which returns an observable collection and I can bind it directly to the angular template, so when new messages arrive or even the other user deletes a message, the chat is updated nicely.

But this implementation has two severe problems: every time I send or receive a message, the last message showing hides because it gets out of the 100 limit. Also, i can't implement infinite scroll to load previous messages since I am unable to find a way to achieve that.

Which is the solution to make the limit range grow accordingly when new messages arrive? How can I implement previous message loading in that scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you have your `messagesRef` set up to be a list of the most recent 100 messages. So if a new message gets added, the oldest message gets dropped. That is working as expected.

It sounds like you want a different behavior: start with the 100 most recent messages, and then add any new messages coming in. For that you need to remove the `limitToLast` from your query. To ensure you still start with (at most) 100 messages, you'll need to add a different criteria: tell the query to start at a specific message.

So in steps:

1. Find the message at position n-100
2. Start a query at that messsage

In code, this should look something like:

```
ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(100).once('child_added', function(snapshot) {
  var oldestKey = snapshot.key;
  this.messagesRef = this.afDB.list(
    `/messages/${this.me.uid}/conversations/${this.contact.uid}/messages`, ref =>  
   ref.orderByKey().startAt(oldestKey)).valueChanges());
})
```

Comment: Yeah! I was trying exactly to do that, but all the approaches I tried led me to a non-observable. Thank you!